# In the Schliemann defense, who does Schliemann refer to?

Tags: opening, gambits, ruy-lopez

The Schliemann's Defence or Schliemann–Jaenisch Gambit refers to the moves 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 f5.

f5 is of course a gambit move by black typically known as the Jaenisch Gambit when white plays the Ruy Lopez scenario. Questions is: Who was Schliemann? Is the name referring to a person or is this some creative term?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the section of the Wikipedia page on the [Ruy Lopez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruy_Lopez#Schliemann_Defence:_3...f5), it's named after a German lawyer, Adolf Karl Wilhelm Schliemann (1817-1872), although it doesn't say why his name is attached to it.

However, the German Wikipedia page on [Adolph Schliemann](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolph_Schliemann) ([English translation](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolph_Schliemann&prev=search)), indicates he was a strong master who contributed to the early theory of the line.

Answer (score 4):

Russian Wikipedia says that Schliemann [was one of the first player who started to use Jaenisch Gambit in the Spanish Opening](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD,_%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84#%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84_%D0%A8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD_%E2%80%94_%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82) (aka Ruy Lopez). That is why it is often called Schliemann defense.